# ¿Alguien sabe cómo podría optimizar este código?

Tags: java, while

*Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de dejar solo un while o si existe otra condición que me ayude a reducir el código*

> Los cont son contadores y la cant es la cantidad

```
int cant, contA=0, contB=0, contC=0, contD=0;
while(cant>=1000) {
    cant-=1000;
    contA++;
}
while(cant>=500) {
    cant-=500;
    contB++;
}
while(cant>=200) {
    cant-=200;
    contC++;
}
while(cant>=100) {
    cant-=100;
    contD++;
}
```

Comment: ¿Por qué hacer un montón de ciclos e iteraciones cuando basta con hacer una división? Para saber los valores de cont, basta con dividir y utilizar el operdador de resto. Para nada necesitas iterar.

Comment: @JaimeMenendez Yo supuse que era un ejemplo en simple de otro problema mayor

Answer (score 2):

Tu código se asemeja al algoritmo de la división: restas sucesivas de un número **a** a un número **b** hasta que **b** sea menor que **a**. En **b** quedaría el resto. El cociente sería la cantidad de veces que pudiste restar.

Este código sería equivalente, más compacto y eficiente:

```
int cant = 1000;

int contA = cant / 1000;
cant %= 1000;
int contB = cant / 500;
cant %= 500;
int contC = cant / 200;
cant %= 200;
int contD = cant / 100;
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://ideone.com/8Ze38C).

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, y definitivamente la forma más clara y eficiente de hacerlo. Los ciclos ahí no tenían ningún sentido.